# Unable to Create Chart in Highcharts and id is undefined

Tags: jquery, json, charts, highcharts, jquery-ajaxq

*Hi 
i am building a pie chart by passing json array to drawchart it displaying labels of chart but unable to find the chart.i need a donut chart where each slice is clickable which carries a id as it parameter when i click the slice it need to open a another chart of that particular slice[image: this is the final out put what i am able to see]*

```js
  <script>
       $(document).ready(function () {
           $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
               url: "bar.aspx/DistrictAnalysis",
               data: "{}",
               dataType: "json",
               success: function (Result) {
                   Result = Result.d;
                   var data = [];
                   for (var i in Result) {
                       //var jsondata = new Array(Result[i].City, Result[i].DevelopmentPercentage, Result[i].ID);
                       var jsondata = { city: Result[i].City, DevelopmentPercentage: Result[i].DevelopmentPercentage, ID: Result[i].ID }
                       data.push(jsondata);
                   }
                   DreawChart(data);
                   console.log(data);
                   
               },
               error: function (Result) {
                   alert("Error");
               }
           });
      
           function DreawChart(series) {
  
           $('#container').highcharts({
               chart: {
                   plotBackgroundColor: null,
                   plotBorderWidth: null,
                   plotShadow: false,
                   type: 'pie'
               },
               title: {
                   text: 'Village Development Measuring System'
               },
               tooltip: {
                   formatter: function () {
                       return '<b>' + this.point.city + '</b>: ' + this.point.DevelopmentPercentage + ' %';
                   }
               },
         
               plotOptions: {
                   pie: {
                       allowPointSelect: true,
                       cursor: 'pointer',
                       dataLabels: {
                           enabled: true,
                           format: '<b>{point.city}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                           style: {
                               color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                           },
                           connectorColor: 'silver'
                       }
                   }
               },
             
               series: [
                  {
                      data: series,
                     type: 'pie',
                     dataType: 'json',
                      animation: false,
                      point: {
                          events: {
                              click: function (event) {
                                  //var id = this.ID;
                                  
                                  //alert(id);
                                 
                                  ////alert(event.point.ID);
                                  //alert(this.point.ID);
                                  //alert(this.x [![able to get id but chart cannot be created][2]][2]+ " " + this.y);
                              }
                          }
                      }
                  }
               ],
           });
       }
       });
   </script>
[![able to get id but chart cannot be created][1]][1]
```

```html
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: have you check the case of `Id`, it should be same as you are passing from code ? Also you should use `{point.City}` instead of `{point.name}` and `point.DevelopmentPercentage` instead of `point.percentage`

Comment: i am unable to get data if i use point.City, point.DevelopmentPercentage but if u look into image its a json object what i am able to get but bot able to bind here

Comment: you are converting jason data to array try this : `DreawChart(Result);`

Comment: if that would be the case i wont get chart

Comment: can you create a fiddle?

Comment: How your data does it look like (could you paste series JSON) ?

Comment: hi sebastian bochan:it look as object [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Comment: if you can see my code which i commented if i look at that json it   var jsondata = new Array(Result[i].City, Result[i].DevelopmentPercentage, Result[i].ID);  the result json object is Seshapuram,25,ab79b0f8-d047-41b1-bd04-020f95ee0e55,Ithepalle,25,2a1c3542-70b8-4b9c-be26-079aea09eea6,Mittapalem,25,f88112da-fc2a-498c-902f-112d1fa2c806, and so on if i use this json code i am unable to get id in click of the slice

Comment: Hi Phani. Let's focus on a single problem at a time. I assume that your data is valid are loaded successfully. Could you use exemplary data and show your problem in JSFiddle? I started the demo for you here with guessed JSON - http://jsfiddle.net/9e79t2sp/ A data point needs to have y numberic value, so you could fix this by setting DevelopmentPercentage as y of a point - example: http://jsfiddle.net/9e79t2sp/1/

Comment: @KacperMadej really You done a great job its working awesome.finally i got output cheers..!thankyou..

Comment: @Phani Glad to hear that your chart is working now. I posted this as an answer, since it helped in resolving your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's focus on a single problem at a time. I assume that your data is valid are loaded successfully. It is possible to use exemplary data and show your problem in a JSFiddle example - http://jsfiddle.net/9e79t2sp/ (problem recreated)

A data point needs to have y numberic value, so you could fix this by setting `DevelopmentPercentage` as `y` of a point - example: http://jsfiddle.net/9e79t2sp/1/ (solution)

Solution code:

```
$(function() {
  // paste your exemplary Result JSON data into Result variable
  var Result = {"d":[{"City":"NYC","DevelopmentPercentage":42,"ID":1234},{"City":"Berlin","DevelopmentPercentage":72,"ID":2345},{"City":"Tokyo","DevelopmentPercentage":92,"ID":5432}]};

  //success: function (Result) {
  Result = Result.d;
  var data = [];
  for (var i in Result) {
    //var jsondata = new Array(Result[i].City, Result[i].DevelopmentPercentage, Result[i].ID);
    var jsondata = {
      city: Result[i].City,
      y: Result[i].DevelopmentPercentage,
      ID: Result[i].ID
    }
    data.push(jsondata);
  }
  DreawChart(data);
  console.log(data);
  //} //end of success function

  function DreawChart(series) {
    $('#container').highcharts({
      chart: {
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBorderWidth: null,
        plotShadow: false,
        type: 'pie'
      },
      title: {
        text: 'Village Development Measuring System'
      },
      tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
          return '<b>' + this.point.city + '</b>: ' + this.point.y + ' %';
        }
      },

      plotOptions: {
        pie: {
          allowPointSelect: true,
          cursor: 'pointer',
          dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            format: '<b>{point.city}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
            style: {
              color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
            },
            connectorColor: 'silver'
          }
        }
      },

      series: [{
        data: series,
        type: 'pie',
        dataType: 'json',
        animation: false,
        point: {
          events: {
            click: function(event) {
              //var id = this.ID;

              //alert(id);

              ////alert(event.point.ID);
              //alert(this.point.ID);
              //alert(this.x [![able to get id but chart cannot be created][2]][2]+ " " + this.y);
            }
          }
        }
      }],
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `point.events.click` callback `this` refers to the point clicked, so no need to de-reference it to `this.point.ID`

```
series: [{
    // ....
    point: {
       events: {
         click: function (event) {
           // the ID field of the point
           var id = this.ID;
           // the whole series of the point
           var series = this.series;
         }
       }
    }
```

Comment: please create a JSFiddle then

Comment: You are constructing your series wrong: instead of `var jsondata = new Array(Result[i].City, Result[i].DevelopmentPercentage, Result[i].ID)` you should write var `jsondata = { city: Result[i].City, percentage: Result[i].DevelopmentPercentage, ID: Result[i].ID }`

Comment: Martin Schneider :it look some thing cool able to get id but chart is not able to display means a visual representation while debug i found the id